# After decrypting a TLS record, how do I know what decompression to apply, if any?

Tags: gzip, deflate, brotli

I successfully implemented TLS 1.3 decryption for specific records, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to go get readable plain text (assume it is compressed).

The TLS record does not include any data about payload compression.
Say that for example the compression is gzip, do I need to concatenate several TLS records spanning the same gzipped payload in order for decompression to succeed or can I decompress each one independently?

Comment: IF compression is done at TLS level each record is done separately but due to attacks like CRIME most admins and many implementations now prohibit TLS-level compression. (In particular TLS1.3 doesn't even define it.) If compression is done at a higher level like HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, MIME (including S/MIME), FTP, various databases (MSSQL, postgres, MySQL, OraDB, etc.) it depends on that higher level and may vary all over the place.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, the TLS version in question is 1.3 so I expect the compression at the HTTP level. But is there any way to read what compression was used purely looking at the decrypted TLS record? Surely browser don't just "try" decompressing it blindly untill some works.

Comment: Browser (or other app) reads the entire response -- all records -- and processes it, first doing decompression if any and then parsing and processing the data in it (which might be HTML, CSS, JS, JPEG etc). For HTTP it should go by the HTTP headers (Content-Encoding and Content-Type) but if those are omitted (or wrong?!) some browsers, especially IE, have been known to guess, often getting it wrong and causing problems; this is usually called 'content sniffing' or 'MIME/media sniffing' which you can search for.

Answer (score 0):

> Say that for example the compression is gzip, do I need to concatenate several TLS records spanning the same gzipped payload in order for decompression to succeed or can I decompress each one independently ?

Depends - if the payload was compressed as a whole then chopped up in pieces for each TLS record, you have to concatenate them, but if the payload was first chopped up then compressed you can decompress it piece-by-piece.

Comment: Is there any indication which way it is done at the binary level?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 2246](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2246) identifies one byte in the message structure that is the compression method. 0 means no compression. [RFC 3749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3749) says that 1 means deflate, and [RFC 3943](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3943.html) allocates 64 for LZSS. [According to the IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/comp-meth-ids/comp-meth-ids.xhtml), that's all of them.

The compression methods are "stateful", which means you have to decompress the records as a stream, not individually.

Comment: I have updated the question to include TLS version, that is 1.3.

Comment: For TLS 1.3, the payload _is not compressed_. The contents of the payload are a matter of agreement between the client and the server. It is possible that those contents are, by that agreement, compressed somehow, but that has nothing to do with TLS.

Comment: When during the handshake or before application data is sent is such an agreement negotiated?

Comment: Such an agreement is long, long before the handshake or transmission. Likely many years before in establishing the contents of the application layer. Is the application HTTPS? Then around the year 2000. Learn about the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). TLS is at the presentation layer. You're asking about the content of the TLS packets, which is the application layer.